Improving Oracle query performance using a global temporary table
Context - Oracle DB
I'm using the following query in an incremental loading framework to track the IDs of deleted rows from the source.
Data is incrementally loaded into ABC_INCR_TAB table and the source of data is ABC_VIEW view.
When new or modified rows are in the ABC_VIEW, we can pick them up and load them into ABC_INCR_TAB.
An integration framework uses this ABC_INCR_TAB and data is loaded to a SQL server table or any other destination.
When there are rows deleted from the source (ABC_VIEW), we have to remove them from the ABC_INCR_TAB and also we have to make sure we keep track of those deleted records so that we can delete them from the SQL server or any other integration we have on the other end.
What we do is store the IDs of deleted rows in another table so that we can use that to clean the SQL server tables.
The current query looks like this.
INSERT INTO DEL_ROWS_TAB d
(ID)
SELECT
ID
FROM ABC_INCR_TAB t
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
SELECT 1 FROM ABC_VIEW b
WHERE t.NO_KEY = b.NO_KEY
AND t.VAL = b.VAL
AND t.LINE = b.LINE
AND t.ITEM = b.ITEM
)

We have some performance issues and looking for ways to improve this.
We are thinking of using a Global temporary table holding only the 4 keys of ABC_VIEW and using that temporary table in the above query.
the ABC_VIEW is a complex view joining 4 tables and there are function calls in that as well.
As of now ABC_INCR_TAB and ABC_VIEW contain about 40 million records.
Is using the temporary table a bad idea?
Any other suggestions?
Update
Explain plan

Note that this is from a test DB containing only about 250K rows.
TAB1, 2, 3, 4 are the tables in the ABC_VIEW.

Is there a way you can send more details like the explain plan  and the DDL for the tables invled.

@HimanshuKandpal added the "explain plan"

One thing I see is the optimizer is using nested loop, as pointed by @Paul can you use a hint to use /*+ use_hash(b t) */  and see if it uses hash join and you see any performance gain.

If I had to guess, you are probably doing nested loops + index access against too much data. Usually when looking for missing rows we have to compare two equally large datasets, so a hash join is almost always preferable. As I don't know your data, here's some hints that while possibly unnecessary will probably make that happen for you. Check the execution plan to be sure. You want to see full table scans and a hash join and some PX operations:
INSERT INTO DEL_ROWS_TAB d (ID)
SELECT /*+ NO_MERGE(b) USE_HASH(t b) FULL(t) PARALLEL(8) */ 
       t.ID
  FROM ABC_INCR_TAB t
       LEFT OUTER JOIN ABC_VIEW b ON t.NO_KEY = b.NO_KEY
                                 AND t.VAL = b.VAL
                                 AND t.LINE = b.LINE
                                 AND t.ITEM = b.ITEM
 WHERE b.no_key is null

It usually helps to rewrite using normal joins rather than subqueries. You certainly have more control over the query when you do.
GTTs are not a help here. They would in fact hurt you by disallowing any parallel query. All you need is standard query tuning. Now your view (ABC_VIEW) might be doing a whole bunch of other worrisome things that can cause issues, but we can't see that here.
